# How would I compile an Assembly file so it is executable on an Android device?

Tags: android, assembly, arm64, termux

So I wanted to play around with the language called Porth (https://github.com/tsoding/porth) but it seems like it isn't supported for Androids, it still returns an .asm file to me through the compile function: [image: Ran compile and la's]
How would I compile the .asm file so it can be ran on my Android?
My `uname -a` output:
`Linux localhost 4.9.186-perf-g10af704 #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Dec 27 14:28:21 WIB 2020 aarch64 Android`

Thanks for any answer in advance!

Comment: You can't. Assembly language is CPU specific, and an assembly file for the X64 CPU doesn't run on an Android device (typically an ARM CPU).

Comment: If you had an x86-64 Android system, it might be possible to do something involving `nasm` and `ld`.  Since you have an AArch64 Android system, it can't run natively.  It might be possible to use an emulator like qemu, IDK.

Comment: Windows 11 and Android.